# different fields setting for ModelSerializer in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple ModelSerializer, and I want to use different fields for lists/details like below, is it possible?

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Item
    list_fields = ('id', 'name')
    detailed_fields = ('id', 'name', 'long_column')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django-rest-framework serializer different fields in multiple views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44063644/django-rest-framework-serializer-different-fields-in-multiple-views)

Answer (score 7):

**Update: May 23, 2019**

A better answer can be found here: [stackoverflow.com/a/44070743/225767](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44070743/225767)

(thanks for the comment [@uhbif19](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225767/uhbif19))

**Original answer:**

What I would personally do is have a different serializer for lists vs. detail. The ModelViewSet has a `list()` and `retrieve()` method. In the example below, I overrode the `retrieve()` method and set the `serializer_class` attribute to the declared "detail" serializer. When it calls `super()`, we are now using the detail serializer. The `list()` will continue to use the `ItemListSerializer`.

On a side note, if you are going to continue using this pattern, it might be in your best interest to create your own ModelViewSet class with custom `list_fields` and `detail_fields`.

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

class ItemListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('id', 'name')


class ItemDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'long_column')


class ItemViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemListSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.serializer_class = ItemDetailSerializer
        return super(ItemViewSet, self).retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I guess that this code may broke, if you will user `list` right after `retrieve` call.
To use different serializers for different endpoints proper approach will be to override `get_serializer_class()` .

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44070743/225767

Comment: As of 2019, this overriding get_serializer_class is definitely the better solution.